# VBA and DOM to fill out input box, in a frame (code here)

Tags: vba, dom

I have made references to the MSHTML library and MS Internet Controls setup, and I am trying to fill out a form using a variable.  The main page consists of 3 frames, and the "top" frame is where my form is located.  The code below will work, if I talk to the frame directly, with the form in the frame being called "NavPage". and the Cnum being the name of the element i want to add a value to, then click a button to retrieve the number

```
Dim HTMLDoc2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set HTMLDoc2 = Browser.document

HTMLDoc2.forms("NavPage").CNum.Value = "12345" 'will change this to become a variable
HTMLDoc2.forms("Navpage").GetCase.Click
```

Question is, how do I reference to the first top frame using DOM, because right now, it doesnt work, and it spits "Object variable or With block variable not set" at me.  Thanks for any insight, as theres not much to be found concerning VB about this

Comment: What enrvironment are you working in? VB (Visual Studio) and VBA (MS Office) are not the same.

Comment: I am working in VBA, sorry, should've clarified that

Comment: OK, in which program? Excel? Word?

Comment: I am working through Excel. I ultimately intend to pull numbers as variables from say, Cell A1, and then input it into that form field.  I can do that now, if I navigate to the source frame, but the main frame is dependent upon whats entered into the top frame.

Comment: might i add, looking around at i think javascript, they were able to do something like ".document.frames(0).form("name").(elementname).XXXXX " but i havent gotten that to work or to recognize my form. I'm fairly new, and especially to interacting with web elements..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this to reference the document in the first frame:

```
Set HTMLDoc2 = Browser.document.frames(0).document
```

Comment: This gives me "member not found".  Let me ask you as well, what are the ways to index a frame? by index number and name? also how do I figure out the index numbers?

Comment: The index numbers should be as they appear in the HTML source for the frameset.  `document.frames("frameName").document` should also work.  Some code here (from John_w) which shows how to loop through the frames: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/429253-execute-javascript-code-webpage-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: I think the frame is pulling through a javascript servlet.  Ultimately, what it brings back is html, so im thinking thats why a direct link to navigate to the frame source works, but linking from the main page wont work.  Do you think there is a way around this? And if so, which way would you recommend?

Comment: Have you tried waiting a little while for the page in the frame to load?  As long as it's loaded your code should work...

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly after including a wait timer. Id buy you a beer if you take paypal lol

Comment: Ive been attacking this thing for a few days, adding watches and trying to figure it out.  Such a simple thing, so easily over-looked. Rookie mistake! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Easy to do - the page seems to be "loaded" because the top-level frameset document is "complete", but then each frame's content has its own separate timeline.